# I can't figure out the bug on cs50 pset4 serpia filter. The expected figures and the actual looks the same but still giving a error

Tags: c, cs50

I am doing cs50 pset4 sepia filter. The [tests results from check50](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/00d11066645eaec3455321c5b7ee2e03b3500f84) show that the last two tests fail, but all the other tests are okay. I can't figure out what is the problem, because the expected output and my actual output are the same.

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float orginalRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            float originalGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            float originalBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            
            float spRed = round(.393 * orginalRed + .769 *  originalGreen + .189 *  originalBlue);
            float spGreen = round(.349 *  orginalRed + .686 * originalGreen + .168 *  originalBlue);
            float spBlue = round(.272 *  orginalRed + .534 *  originalGreen + .131 *  originalBlue);

            if (spRed > 255.0)
            {
                spRed = 225;
            }
          
            if (spBlue > 255.0)
            {
               spBlue = 255;
            }
            if (spGreen > 255.0)
            {
               spGreen = 255;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = spRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = spGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = spBlue;

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The one thing sticking out is that you set red to `225` if it exceeds `255`. That looks wrong.

Anyway, simplify:

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            RGBTRIPLE x = image[i][j];

#define X(r, g, b) fmin(255, round(r * x.rgbtRed + g * x.rgbtGreen + b * x.rgbtBlue))
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = X(.393, .769, .189);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = X(.349, .686, .168);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = X(.272, .534, .131);
#undef X
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the results from the 2 [check50 tests](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/00d11066645eaec3455321c5b7ee2e03b3500f84) that were wrong, line 7-9 of the expected output is:
255 251 195
255 255 214
255 255 232

Then lines 7-9 of the actual output are:
225 251 195
225 255 214
225 255 232

The red values of the actual output should have been rounded to 255 instead of 225. The bug is at line 17, where you say:
`spRed = 225;` instead of `spRed = 255;`

I also replaced the if statements with a [ternary operator](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/cpp/ternary) and replaced the use of variables orginalRed, orginalBlue, and orginalGreen with the actual pixel values, for better run time and simplicity.

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            float spRed   = round(.393 * image[i][x].rgbtRed + .769 * image[i][x].rgbtGreen + .189 *  image[i][x].rgbtBlue);
            float spGreen = round(.349 * image[i][x].rgbtRed + .686 * image[i][x].rgbtGreen + .168 *  image[i][x].rgbtBlue);
            float spBlue  = round(.272 * image[i][x].rgbtRed + .534 * image[i][x].rgbtGreen + .131 *  image[i][x].rgbtBlue);

            image[i][x].rgbtRed   = (spRed   < 255) ? spRed   : 255;
            image[i][x].rgbtBlue  = (spBlue  < 255) ? spBlue  : 255;
            image[i][x].rgbtGreen = (spGreen < 255) ? spGreen : 255;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The arrays could be the problem also you just return maybe it waits you to return 0 extra. But usually main problem in c I think arrays.
Have you use allocate memorty for this array : image[i][j]